# Get index of for loop when iterating over pandas timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

In my code there is a `for` loop which iterates over pandas timestamps. I need to get the index in the `for` loop. Normally, I would do

```
for idx, day in dates:
```

However, if I try to do that I get the error "'Timestamp' object is not iterable". How can I get the index of the `for` loop? My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
base = pd.Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:00:00+0000')
dt_start = base
total_days = 50
dates = np.array([base + pd.DateOffset(i) for i in xrange(total_days)])
for day in dates:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()`

```
for idx, day in enumerate(dates):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for i in range(len(dates)):
```

this way, you can use indexes for accessing your loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `enumerate`?

```
l = ['a','b','c']
for index, i in enumerate(l):
    print index, i
```

Output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```